# Processing time value for converting to DateTime in pandas without iterating manually?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, datetime, pandas

I'm reading in some data into pandas like this and I really like that it just stitches the "Month" (1-12) and "Date" (1-31) into one.

```
pandas.read_csv("mysheet.csv",parse_dates=[["Month","date"]])
```

The data has the timestamps in separate month, date, and time columns and the time is basically HHMM with no delineation and no leading zeros.

I need to index by time and to do so I'm trying to get everything into a datetime, but without manually iterating through it row by row.

```
def add_timestamps(data):
    time = data["time"]
    minutes = time % 100
    hours = int(time/100)
    data["timestamp"] = "2012-" + str(data["Month"]) + "-" + str(data["date"] + " " + str(hours) + ":" + str(minutes))
```

^ This is my code that I'm using to try to get it all into a proper date and time combined field so I can just do

```
pandas.to_datetime(data["timestamp"],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

And be done with it but I am at a complete loss as to how I should be telling it to set each timestamp FIELD to that combined string rather than this way where this thinks I want to set the entire series to that string.

Also, I get this error:

```
**TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>**
```

I'm not sure why it thinks I'm trying to set it to an int either. Any help and direction is much appreciated!

Comment: Please show a (small) sample dataframe with your actual data.

Comment: @JCooking, You've got 2 answers. Please consider accepting the best answer by clicking on the grey check mark so that it glows to green.[see here for details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) This indicates that your question has been resolved successfully.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it everything at once while reading itself using keyword arguments provided in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
# using the same data per @jezrael
data = StringIO(
'''
Month  date  time
1     4    1350
2     5    1012
3    26    0348
''')

# function to use for processing string columns to datetime instances
date_parse = lambda x: '{} {}'.format(2012, x)
# create a dict mapping of columns to be consolidated into a single timestamp column
date_col_dict = {'timestamp': ['Month', 'date', 'time']}
# `keep_date_col=True` to keep the month/date/time columns and not drop them
kwds = dict(parse_dates=date_col_dict, keep_date_col=True, date_parser=date_parse)
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True, **kwds)
#                 ^----------^ replace this part with your csv filename
```

[image]

Check the `dtypes`:

```
df.dtypes

timestamp    datetime64[ns]
Month                object
date                 object
time                 object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked and with a little modification I was able to figure out how to have it preprocess the times too

Answer (score 1):

You can use [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) for selecting first 2 and last 2 chars for `HH` and `MM`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Month':[1,2,3],
                   'date':[4,5,26],
                   'time':['1350','1012','0348']})

print (data)
   Month  date  time
0      1     4  1350
1      2     5  1012
2      3    26  0348

s = '2012' + '-' + data["Month"].astype(str) \
           + '-' + data["date"].astype(str) + ' ' \
                 + data['time'].str[:2] + ':'  \
                 + data['time'].str[2:] 
print (s)
0     2012-1-4 13:50
1     2012-2-5 10:12
2    2012-3-26 03:48
dtype: object

data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(s) 
#if necessary add format
#data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(s,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") 
print (data)
   Month  date  time           timestamp
0      1     4  1350 2012-01-04 13:50:00
1      2     5  1012 2012-02-05 10:12:00
2      3    26  0348 2012-03-26 03:48:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply; unfortunately there were no leading zeroes so 0348 would be in the files as 348 but your reply gave me a great idea! :)